Wordpress error when using command 'npx @wordpress/create-block@latest'
I'm trying to create my wordpress block using :
npx @wordpress/create-block@latest todo-list

But then, I have this error in console :
 npx @wordpress/create-block todo-list

Creating a new WordPress plugin in the todo-list directory.

Creating a "block.json" file.

Creating a "package.json" file.

Installing `@wordpress/scripts` package. It might take a couple of minutes...

Formatting JavaScript files.

Compiling block.
/Users/user/.npm/_npx/0890e296436e9575/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:59
                error = new Error(message);
                        ^

Error: Command failed with exit code 2: npm run build
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'

My npm version is 10.7.0, NodeJS version : 20.14.0
According to Wordpress docs, required versions are :
NodeJS: 20.10.0 or above
NPM : 10.2.3 or above

Clear the npm cache:
npm cache clean --force

Delete node_modules and package-lock.json:
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json

Reinstall dependencies:
npm install

Run the create block command again:
npx @wordpress/create-block@latest todo-list

This process ensures a clean setup and should help resolve the module error.

Thanks, I already did that but it's still not working
